# How to show that two vertices in a connected component are in the same set? (bi conditional)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms

Show that after all edges are processed by CONNECTED-COMPONENTS, two vertices are in the same connected component if and only if they are in the same set.

The CONNECTED-COMPONENTS algorithm is the following:

[image]

It seems pretty obvious that when we keep adding the vertices of the direct edges of a connected component to a set, eventually the set formed has all the vertices in the connected component - directly connected as well as indirectly connected. 
But how do I formally prove that? Also it seems like a biconditional to me.
I've thought of things like loop-invariant or a proof by contradiction. But unable to exactly figure out what to do. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily show that 
$ \operatorname{Find-Set}(x)=\operatorname{Find-Set}(y)$ implies that $x$ and $y$ are in the same component: It holds initially, and processing a single edge $(u,v)$ does not destroy this property: If $ \operatorname{Find-Set}(x)=\operatorname{Find-Set}(y)$ holds after taking the union, but not before, then each of $x$ is in either $\operatorname{Find-Set}(u)$ or $\operatorname{Find-Set}(v)$, hence in the same component as $u$ or $v$; as $u$ and $v$ are in the same component as witnessed by the edge $(u,v)$, we conclude that $a,b$ are in the same component.

Also, it can never happen that  $ \operatorname{Find-Set}(x)=\operatorname{Find-Set}(y)$ holds before, but not after a step; this is because we are only taking unions all the time.

Now assume $a,b$ are in the same component. Then there are vertices $x_0=a, x_1, \ldots, x_n=b$ such that each $(x_i,x_{i+1})$ is an edge
After the processing of $(x_i,x_{i+1})$ (and from then until the end), we have $ \operatorname{Find-Set}(x_i)=\operatorname{Find-Set}(x_{i+1})$. Thus after processing all edges, we have
$$ \operatorname{Find-Set}(a)=\operatorname{Find-Set}(x_1)=\ldots=\operatorname{Find-Set}(x_n)=\operatorname{Find-Set}(b) $$

In summary, $\operatorname{Find-Set}(a)=\operatorname{Find-Set}(b)$ (after processing all edges) if and only if $a$ and b$ are in the same component.

Comment: I understood the second part where you have shown that two vertices are in same component, then they are in the same set. But I couldn't understand the part where you have proved the vice versa. Initially it holds yes. Processing a single edge doesn't destroy it, yes. But your next sentence seems confusing. Can you please restructure or explain the first paragraph. Thank you.

Comment: ok, I think what you meant is sort of a proof by contradiction. If something for which findset(a)=findset(b) has to be in different component, then after processing it, the findset(a) !=findset(b) should occur but it doesn't. So if it is in findset(a)=findset(b), then (a,b) belong to same component.